# Regular Expression to find "lastname, firstname middlename" format

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find the format "abc, def g" which is a name format "lastname, firstname middlename". I think the best suited method is regex but I do not have any idea in Regex. I tried doing some learning in regex and tried some expression also but no luck. One additional point there may be more than one spaces between the words.

This is what I tried. But this is not working.

```
(([A-Z][,]\s?)*([A-Z][a-z]+\s?)+([A-Z]\s?[a-z]*)*)
```

Need help ! Any idea how I can do this so that only the above expression match.

Thanks !

**ANSWER**

Finally I am using

```
([A-Za-z]+),\\s*([A-Za-z]+)\\s*([A-Za-z]+)
```

Thanks to everyone for the suggestions.

Comment: Please show some code - the string you provided is not even a valid Java string due to invalid escape characters

Comment: @Andreas I think he's showing the regular expression, rather than the Java string literal

Comment: @Andreas - This is the regex that I have tried. But its not matching correctly. :(

Comment: @morgano Sure, but it would be easier if we had a java code sample - otherwise, why the Java tag? ;)

Comment: There are online regular expression testers which can show you the parts of the string which match

Comment: Note: as a general name format, "abc, def g" is pretty lacking. As ajb points out in one of the answers below, real names can have spaces and other non-alpha characters in them: both in the last name, and in the other names. For instance the Dutch surname "van der Heuvel", the Irish surnames "Mac Piarais", "O'Dowd", the first names "Mary Kate" (which is not a first name of Mary and a middle name of Kate) and "Marie-Claire".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sample input is `"lastname, firstname middlename"` - with that, you can use the following regexp to extract lastname, firstname and middlename (with the addition that there might be multiple white spaces, and that there might be both capital and non-capital letters in the strings - also, all parts are mandatory):

```
String input = "Lastname,   firstname   middlename";
String regexp = "([A-Za-z]+),\\s+([A-Za-z]+)\\s+([A-Za-z]+)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
matcher.find();
System.out.println("Lastname  : " + matcher.group(1));
System.out.println("Firstname : " + matcher.group(2));
System.out.println("Middlename: " + matcher.group(3));
```

Short summary:

```
([A-Za-z]+)   First capture group - matches one or more letters to extract the last name
,\\s+         Capture group is followed by a comma and one or more spaces
([A-Za-z]+)   Second capture group - matches one or more letters to extract the first name
\\s+          Capture group is followed by one or more spaces
([A-Za-z]+)   Third capture group - matches one or more letters to extract the middle name
```

This only works if your names contain latin letters only - probably you should use a more open match for the characters:

```
String input = "Müller,   firstname  middlename";
String regexp = "(.+),\\s+(.+)\\s+(.+)";
```

This matches any character for lastname, firstname and middlename.

If the spaces are optional (only the first occurrence can be optional, otherwise we can not distinguish between firstname and middlename), then use `*` instead of `+`:

```
String input = "Müller,firstname  middlename";
String regexp = "(.+),\\s*(.+)\\s+(.+)";
```

---

As @Elliott mentions, there might be other possibilities like using `String.split()` or `String.indexOf()` with `String.substring()` - regular expressions are often more flexible, but harder to maintain, especially for complex expressions.

In either case, implement unit tests with as much different inputs (including invalid ones) as possible so that you can verify that your algorithm is still valid after you modify it.

Comment: Thank you ! This works. And also thank you for the detail description. Just one question, if the spaces are option how to mark that I mean the spaces in between can be 0 - N. How can I mark that in the regex.

Comment: Only the spaces after the comma can be optional - otherwise you can not distinguish between firstname and middlename. Simply use `*` instead of `+` - `*` matches 0 to N while `+` matches 1 to N

Answer (score 6):

I would try and avoid a complicated regex, I would use `String.substring()` and `indexOf()`. That is, something like

```
String name = "Last, First Middle";
int comma = name.indexOf(',');
int lastSpace = name.lastIndexOf(' ');
String lastName = name.substring(0, comma);
String firstName = name.substring(comma + 2, lastSpace);
String middleName = name.substring(lastSpace + 1);
System.out.printf("first='%s' middle='%s' last='%s'%n", firstName,
            middleName, lastName);
```

Output is

```
first='First' middle='Middle' last='Last'
```

Comment: Agree, OP doesn't specify if he/she is going to deal with only English names or "International ones, but using a regex would be more complicated, as there are surnames like "O'hara" or non-english names like "Ramón"

Comment: BTW, if you are talking about "complicated regex" - check this one: http://pastebin.com/HUmPzP5M :-) (disclaimer: I am also **not** a fan of complex regular expressions)

Comment: Regex may be complex but its more prominent. The code which is written above needs many if checks before you can call substring or it could lead to indexout of bound. But any way thanks for the answer. +1 for it.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to matching the `lastname, firstname middlename` directly, you could use String.split and provide a regexp that matches the separators, instead. For instance:

```
static String[] lastFirstMiddle(String input){
    String[] result=input.split("[,\\s]+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(result));
    return result;
}
```

I tested this with inputs

```
"Müller,   firstname  middlename"
"Müller,firstname  middlename"
 "O'Gara, Ronan Ramón"
```

Note: this approach fails with surnames that contain spaces, for instance "van der Heuvel", "de Valera", "mac Piarais" or "bin Laden" but then again, OP's original specification does not seem to admit of spaces in the surname (or the other names. I work with a "Mary Kate". That's her first name, not first and middle). There's an interesting page about personal names at http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names

Answer (score 1):

```
^([a-zA-Z]+)\s*,\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\s+([a-zA-Z]+)$
```

I think you are looking for this.just grab the groups to get your needs.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/6

Comment: Just add more possible characters in the words, for instance: O'Hara is a valid surname but your regex doesn't find it

Comment: @morgano OP's regex doesnt have it.So i am not really sure he is looking for that.

Comment: @morgano If you go down that path you will get lost in the woods. You have to deal with hyphenated names, people with two or more middle names, Jr. or Sr. or III after people's names, Dutch names like "van der Heuvel", double first names like "Mary Beth", places where they put the surname first, Spanish names with patronymics where the surname is actually in the middle and might be followed with "de" or "y", middle initials, people whose first names are two initials, Louis C.K., etc. There is no way to get it right in all cases.

Comment: @ajb, you're right, the problem seems to be more complicated than just finding `word, word word`, maybe you should comment this to the OP instead of me as he/she doesn't delimit the problem properly (using only latin letters or a set of valid characters, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I think this one will also work and a bit shorter than yours:

```
([A-Z][a-z]*)(?:,\s*)?
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/52Mn6a23IB)

Or you can use split using this regex:

```
(,?\s+)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
def rearrange_name(name):
  result = re.search(r"^([\w \.-]*), ([\w \.-]*)$", name)  #Included extra characters i.e. .- to be captured in our groups in the event they are found.
  #result = re.search(r"^([\w .-]*), ([\w .-]*)$", name)  #seems to be also working without escaping the period
  if result == None:
    return name
  return "{} {}".format(result[2], result[1])

name=rearrange_name("Raila, Odinga M.")
print(name)`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def rearrange_name(name):
    result = re.search(r"^([\w \.-]*), ([\w \.-]*)$", name)
    if result == None:
        return name
    return "{} {}".format(result[2], result[1])

name = rearrange_name("Erick, Bett K.")
print(name)
```