# Angular 6 input function to detect first and last name with comma and space

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

My Angular 6 app has a search input box that will help to search for people in a directory by providing either of these formats as an input:

Case1: "word word" - space is matter, treat the string as "first last"

Case2: "word, word" - treat the string as "last, first"

Case3: "word " - treat the string as "last"

The cases above will be considered as a successful case which triggers the API query to be sent. I did some research that I could not build a custom angular pipe for this, because a pipe is for displaying data, not receiving data. So i just gonna build a parse function that will test the string.

My approach now for case1 and case3 is overlapped with each other.

```
transformInput(inputValue) {
    const case1 = /(([A-Za-z])+(\s)+[A-Za-z]*)/;
    const case2 = //NOT SURE;
    const case3 = /(^([A-Za-z]*)+\s)/;

    if (case1.test(inputValue) {
    console.log('case1')
    } else if (case2.test(inputValue)) {
    console.log('case2')
    } else if...
}
```

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Also, essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801247/regular-expression-to-find-lastname-firstname-middlename-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work: `\w+,?\s?\w*`

If you want to be more specific you can use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `\w`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hae0M4/2)

Comment: this works to test for all 3 cases. But, I need for each case so 3 regexes.

Comment: Have you read up on basic regular expressions? That should be a simple task. `\w+\s+\w+`, `\w+,\s+\w+` and `\w+`