# Regular Expression Separate columns Fullname into Lastname, Firstname Middlename(or Initial) Format

Tags: r, regex

I have a FULLNAME column, I want to split it into 3 columns: LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLE_NAME_INITIAL
Different cases are included in the example below. I think it is easy to look at my code than my description.

```
df <- data.frame(FULLNAME = c("John, Smith J.", 
                          "David, Cameron", 
                          "Adam-Steve, Johnson M.", 
                          "Antonio, Zang-Chi K", 
                          "Joan Philippe, Luis Carlos", 
                          "Dave, Jr., Danny Rock",
                          "Jake, Joan-Anberto",
                          "Annie, L.K Selena",
                          "Anna, P. Zhei"))
```

## Output:

```
       LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME MIDDLE_NAME_INITIAL
1          John        Smith             J.
2         David      Cameron               
3    Adam-Steve      Johnson             M.
4       Antonio     Zang-Chi              K
5 Joan Philippe         Luis         Carlos
6     Dave, Jr.        Danny           Rock
7          Jake Joan-Anberto               
8         Annie       Selena            L.K
9          Anna         Zhei             P.
```

I have google things and I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801247/regular-expression-to-find-lastname-firstname-middlename-format)
I tried different ways one of them is `pattern = "(.+),\\s*(.+)\\s+(.+)"` , but it failed to get the expected output. 
Every recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using stringr or base R?

Comment: I tried separate(FULLNAME, into = c("LASTNAME", "FIRSTNAME", "MIDDLE_NAME_INITIAL"), sep = "pattern")

Comment: You can't use `separate`, because your data are not column-wise. Initials are sometimes in Group 2, sometimes in Group 3. It means you just can't use `split` in any form.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for me in this case? Or I have to accept to lose some data of initials

Comment: Your expected output is strange, `Carlos` and `Rock` are not initials.

Comment: @Wiktor It can be Initials or Middle name

Answer (score 2):

Requires PCRE-style regular expression support. So, yeah...

```
/
^                               # start at the beginning of the string
(
  \w+                           # first name
  (?:[- ]\w+)*                  # optional second part of first name
  (?:,(?![^,]*$)\s[\w.]+)?      # optional comma-separated addendum to 1st name
)
,\s                             # delimiting comma and space
(?=                             # assert existence of last name
  .*?                           # bridge gap to last name (pre-initials)
  (\w{2,}(?:-\w{2,})*)          # (optionally multi-part) last name
)
(?=                             # assert existence of optional initials
  (?:.*?\b(\w\.\w\b|\w\b\.?|(?<!-)\w+$))?  # optional initals or middle name
)
/x                              # flag: enable free-spacing mode for expression
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/V0OZMn/2).

I have no idea about R; this is just an example of how to capture the different name parts, so far as possible.

**Edit**: updated the expression to treat additional name parts like middle name initials.

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

```
([\w\s.,-]+)(?:[^,]*,\s){1,}([\w.-]+)\s*([\w.-]*)
```

Here you can see how it works: https://regexr.com/50oef

I don't know R language, so let me show the example using Java:

```java
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(
        "John, Smith J.",
        "David, Cameron",
        "Adam-Steve, Johnson M.",
        "Antonio, Zang-Chi K",
        "Joan Philippe, Luis Carlos",
        "Dave, Jr., Danny Rock",
        "Jake, Joan-Anberto",
        "Annie, L.K Selena",
        "Anna, P. Zhei");

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\s.,-]+)(?:[^,]*,\\s){1,}([\\w.-]+)\\s*([\\w.-]*)");

int k = 0;
for (String item : items) {
    Matcher m = regex.matcher(item);

    if (m.find()) {
        String group1 = m.group(1);
        String group2 = m.group(2);
        String group3 = m.group(3);

        boolean initialsInGroup2 = group2.contains(".");
        boolean initialsInGroup3 = group3.contains(".");

        System.out.println(++k
                + (!"".equals(group1) ? String.format("%15s", group1) : "")
                + (!"".equals(group2) ? String.format("%15s", initialsInGroup2 ? group3 : group2) : "")
                + (!"".equals(group3) ? String.format("%10s", initialsInGroup3 ? group3 : initialsInGroup2 ? group2 : group3) : ""));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1           John          Smith        J.
2          David        Cameron
3     Adam-Steve        Johnson        M.
4        Antonio       Zang-Chi         K
5  Joan Philippe           Luis    Carlos
6      Dave, Jr.          Danny      Rock
7           Jake   Joan-Anberto
8          Annie         Selena       L.K
9           Anna           Zhei        P.
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your data is not in a fixed column-wise order, I think there is too much conditional logic to try to capture all this in a maintainable regex in R. I'm not even sure how you could tell which names are first names and which are middle names when initials are not used since the ordering is inconsistent.

However, based on the rules implied by how you have manually parsed the names, here is some code that can replicate these rules:

```r
extract_initials <- function(x)
{
  y <- lapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(z) z[nzchar(z)])
  sapply(y, function(z){
    if(length(z) == 1) return("")
    else if(!all(grepl("[a-z]", z)))
      return(paste(grep("[a-z]", z, invert = T, value = T), collapse = " "))
    else return(paste(z[length(z)], collapse = " "))
  })
}

extract_first <- function(x)
{
  y <- lapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(z) z[nzchar(z)])
  sapply(y, function(z){
    if(length(z) == 1) return(z)
    else if(!all(grepl("[a-z]", z)))
      return(paste(grep("[a-z]", z, value = T), collapse = " "))
    else return(paste(z[-length(z)], collapse = " "))
  })
}

split_name <- function(x)
{
  partlist <- strsplit(x, ",(?=[^,]*$)", perl = TRUE)
  surnames <- sapply(partlist, `[`, 1)
  forenames <- sapply(partlist, `[`, 2)
  data.frame(surname = surnames, 
             first = extract_first(forenames), 
             middle = extract_initials(forenames),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

and it works as simply as this:

```r
split_name(df$FULLNAME)
#>         surname        first middle
#> 1          John        Smith     J.
#> 2         David      Cameron       
#> 3    Adam-Steve      Johnson     M.
#> 4       Antonio     Zang-Chi      K
#> 5 Joan Philippe         Luis Carlos
#> 6     Dave, Jr.        Danny   Rock
#> 7          Jake Joan-Anberto       
#> 8         Annie       Selena    L.K
#> 9          Anna         Zhei     P.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It is weird when I run this and it returns "Error in strsplit(x, ",(?=[^,]*$)", perl = TRUE) : non-character argument"

Comment: @MichaelJohnson  You need to ensure that df$FULLNAME is a character, not a factor. Try `split_name(as.character(df$FULLNAME))`